# E/Adreno200-EGL(8183): eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, textures

I am building an android opengl es 2.0 application. I am drawing squares in a circle, and with the user's movements left and right I am moving the squares. I am applying textures on the squares and keep getting this error:

```
2-19 16:08:25.666: E/Adreno200-EGL(8183): eglLockWindowSurface: failed to map the memory 
for fd=42 offs=6352896
```

I think that it has something to do with the textures. For loading the textures I use:

```
public static int loadTexture(final Context context, Bitmap bmp)
{
    final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

//  GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

    if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
    {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inScaled = false;   // No pre-scaling

        // Read in the resource
        final Bitmap bitmap = bmp;

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

        // Set filtering
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
        // bitmap.recycle();                        
    }

    if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
    {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
    }

    return textureHandle[0];
}
```

Note: with bitmap.recycle() the app does not work.

Also I must say that the onDraw() method is always working and the renderer is NOT set to RENDER_WHEN_DIRTY. I assume that I am loading too many textures and not doing anything to the old ones, but I can't solve this problem for several days now. If someone has a solution, please let me know. I will deeply appreciate any advice or feedback. Thank u in advance!!!

Comment: Hi, have you tried possibly using less textures? Use textures of smaller size, or try to load just a single 2x2 px texture and use it instead of all the textures (if that's possible in your app). Will it cause the same error?